# Invalid Identifier on the SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

On passing the below query , i am getting an error. Can you please tell me what i am passing incorrectly?

```
Select *
from RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL INNER JOIN
     HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS
     ON HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID = RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID
```

Error is ORA-00904: "HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS"."BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  What don't you undertand?

Comment: There is no `BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID` in `HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS`, you can access `etrm.oracle.com`for references. The correct join column is `HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID` and please use table alias

Answer (score 0):

HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID is not a valid column name.